# What is a squashed hourglass?

Tags: meaning

This is a passage from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Heather has Georgie's wavy, browny-blond hair. And Georgie's washed-out blue eye. And she was built like Georgie was in high school, like a **squashed hourglass**. Though Heather was a little taller than Georgie...

What is a squashed hourglass?

Comment: It refers to her body shape, like an hourglass: "Heavy bottom, generous chest".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an hourglass figure

[image]

Here is an hourglass
[image]

.. and here is a squashed hourglass

[image]

Here is someone with a squashed-hourglass figure.

[image]

**Answer**

It refers to a person who has a short and heavy build and yet has a well-defined waist.

Comment: The lady in the image is, I believe, pear-shaped, more than "squashed hourglass".

Comment: Nope. Someone who has a pear-shaped figure has relatively narrow top-half and large hips. A pear is not the the same as an hourglass.  Here's a pear-shape http://www.eveningdresses2012.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Pear-shaped-body-type.png

Comment: We don't see the lady's chest in the *second* image. Perhaps you only needed to explain what 1. *hourglass figure* and 2. *squashed* meant. EDIT: You're such a gentleman :)

Comment: The point about having an hourglass figure is that the person is narrow-waisted. The waist must be narrow in comparison to hips and shoulders/chest.  It is not inconceivable that someone is slightly pear-shaped as well as having an hourglass figure. They are not mutually incompatible.  Pear-shaped relates to the proportion between chest and hips - it says little about the waist.

Answer (score 1):

If you squash something you flatten it. When you squash an empty plastic bottle, you literally shrink its size.

[image]

An hourglass figure describes a woman whose bust and hip measurements match and whose waist is clearly defined. Just like the glass ‘timing’ device that @chasly posted in his answer.

Both girls, Heather and Georgie,  could also be described as being *curvy*, inasmuch they have an ample bosom, generous hips and a narrow waist. Although the author implies they both have small waists, their [torsos](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/torso) are probably short which makes them *look* a bit ‘squashed’.